# youtube playlist returning as '#document' instead of XML doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

When trying to retrieve a playlist using the YouTube developers API v2, I continually get a response in the Chrome console that the loaded file is the wrong type, and is a Document, not XML. Here is the code I am using:

```
$.get('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2',
  function(data)
  {
    var doc = data;
    console.log( data );
  });
```

The result in the console is: `#document` where I am expecting the result to be an XML doc.

Comment: `#document` represents the XML Document. If you want it as text, add `,"text"` after your callback function. jQuery is trying to save you time by automatically converting it into an XML Document for you.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, it's is xml, this is xml representation by jquery

you can use [xml2json](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/)

Answer (score 0):

You sure are getting an xml document from the feed, and if you want to be sure that your jQuery ajax request is recognizing it as such you can specify the "dataType" parameter also like so:

```
$.get('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2',
  function(data)
  {
    console.log( 'An xml feed is being retrieved, true or false:'+($(data).children('feed').length == 1).toString());
  },'xml');
```

or using the longhand $.ajax method, which can help in debugging by using the "error" option as well:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
        console.log( 'An xml feed is being retrieved, true or false:'+($(data).children('feed').length == 1).toString());
    },
    error: function(xhr,stat,err){ console.log(stat+': '+err); }
});
```

Here is an example using the $.ajax method, and indeed it is being recognized as valid xml without even specifying the dataType parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/UZddq/2/

It may be easier to work with json also. You can retrieve the feed from youtube in json format by specifying the "alt" parameter in the url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2&alt=json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log( 'A json feed is being retrieved, true or false:'+data.hasOwnProperty('feed').toString());
    },
    error: function(xhr,stat,err){ console.log(stat+': '+err); }
});
```

Here is the json version example: http://jsfiddle.net/hvFQj/2/